# Does $\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n + 1}}{n(n-1)}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a homework question so I'll show what I've tried.

The integral test gives convergence, but I have to use $tanh$, which is not part of our high-school syllabus.

I've tried doing the limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ both of which give zero as the limit.

D'Almbert's criterion is also inconclusive.

Comment: Limit Comparison with $1/n^{3/2}$ works

Comment: How did you figure out that $1/n^{3/2}$ is the right one to use?

Comment: Numerator is like $\sqrt{n}$ and denominator is like $n^2$ what result?

Comment: the power of $n$ on top  minus the power of $n$ on the bottom (it's a general method).

Comment: @NeutralElement write this as an answer.

Comment: If @NeutralElement writes the general method as part of the answer, then I think keeping this duplicate would be good for people who don't know about it. Alternatively someone can edit the answer given in the previously posted copy of this question.

Comment: @user1176201 I will not write the general method since I find it trivial. But you should try it and if you have a problem with the limit computation try force factoring

Comment: K, so should I delete this question then?

Comment: @user1176201: it is better. I exported my answer in the other thread. Voting for closing.

Comment: K, close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost got it with the comparison test, just have to be more accurate, with the expontent.

$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{n(n-1)}$    behaves asymptotically like $\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$. I think you will take it from here.